# how to store cte and use it inside another cte in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

im trying to do cohort analysis using SQL server
i was looking at this online

```sql
`-- (user_id, cohort_month), each 
with cohort_items as (
  select
    date_trunc('month', U.timestamp)::date as cohort_month,
    id as user_id
  from users U
  order by 1, 2
)
After that, we build user_activities which

-- (user_id, month_number): user X has activity in month number X
WITH user_activities as (
  select
    A.user_id,
    MONTH_DIFF(
      date_trunc('month', A.timestamp)::date,
      C.cohort_month
    ) as month_number
  from public.activities A
  left join cohort_items C ON A.user_id = C.user_id
  group by 1, 2
)
```

how to use cohort_items  is the second cte ?

Comment: You would separate the 2 CTEs with a comma. You do not need the second `WITH` keyword. I.e. `WITH a AS  (...), b AS (SELECT abc FROM a)`

Comment: A CTE can *only* be referenced in the statement it is defined it; it is an **expression**. I *assume* that `After that, we build user_activities which` means that you use the CTE `cohort_items` in a statement and that statement is terminated. As such you would need to redefine the CTE `cohort_items` in the latter statement. If you find you need to use the CTE multiple times you might be better off putting the data into a temporary table.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using SQL Server though? `date_trunc` is *not* a built in T-SQL function. Also, syntax like `GROUP BY {ordinal position` is a terrible habit.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cohort_items as (
  select
    date_trunc('month', U.timestamp)::date as cohort_month,
    id as user_id
  from users U
)
,user_activities as (
  select
    A.user_id,
    MONTH_DIFF(
      date_trunc('month', A.timestamp)::date,
      C.cohort_month
    ) as month_number
  from public.activities A
  left join cohort_items C ON A.user_id = C.user_id
  group by 1, 2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this.

```
WITH X (SELET * FROM TABLE),
Y AS (SELECT * FROM X);
```

Comment: You can't use a `SELET` statement within a common table expression nor can a CTE stand on its own without being followed by a single statement that references the CTE.

Comment: Please have a look into this: This a running solution and I have already used it as part of my project;

WITH A AS (

SELECT  *
 FROM SchemaName.TableName

),
B AS (
SELECT * FROM A

)

SELECT * FROM B;

Comment: Sure, you could use three `select` statements, but The Answer using one `selet` and one `select` doesn't even pass the parsing test.

Comment: @HABO: Kindly mark this useful. My idea was to give him direction.